# Where's the guidance about what you can ask about on Meta?

Tags: support, meta, scope

Reading another (downvoted) question, I wondered "gee, are you allowed to ask about technical issues with SO on Meta".

So I clicked "Ask Question", then clicked "asking help" and ... found myself at the Stack Overflow asking help.

Are there guidelines for Meta questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the help menu is a link: [What's Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). It describes what is and is not on topic here:

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does.